# Opening of Shapefile in Grads

Tags: grads

I have shape file (abc.shp, abc.shx, abc.dbf) in my SampleDatasets folder. When I try to open this shapefile in Qgis it is opening well but when I call this shape file in Grads then it is not opening. please help me to use correct command. thanks in advance

Comment: Add the data in your post.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this command to opening .shp file. It works for me

```
draw shp path\file.shp
```

Comment: I tried this but it is not working. After calling shape file I get "no scaling environment"

Comment: which version of grads are you using?

Comment: version OpenGrADS-2.2

Comment: Make sure the .shp data is in the same folder as the data that you open in grads, then "display" any variable from your dataset, then use the draw shp

Comment: yes a have placed .shp in same folder. By the way which coordinate system is used in Grads

Comment: I think that his shapefile has a problem. Maybe, you can add in your post so we can check? I had this issue before but it is related to the projection of the shapefile. Please check.